# Animated GIF while database connects in WPF

Tags: sql-server, wpf, wpf-controls, animated-gif

I am working on an application that connects to Database as soon as it opens. Sometimes, it takes about 10-15 seconds before the database file gets connected and until then, no controls are loaded, it just loads a blank window and the cursor shows working. I tried using [this](http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/documentation) library to use an animated GIF but it is not loading it before trying DB connection. I am using SQL Server Express and connecting to an mdf file. I tried placing code to display the **`<image/>`** before the ***SqlConnection and SqlDataAdapter Objects*** but even that didn't help. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you get data from db your UI freezing. You should use BackgroundWorker (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). I also recommended to use BusyIndicator (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all the loading processes on a different thread,
Best way to do this is to use a BackgroundWorker

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Initialize
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += 
    new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);

Usage
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

```
    for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
        }
    }
}
```